# Name webpack chunks from react-loadable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dynamic-import, react-loadable

I've successfully added react-loadable library in my project to enable code splitting, the only problem I've found is that the chunks generated by webpack are not named, they are given integer names.

My code for react-loadable use is

```js
const AppRootLoadable = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "app" */ './App'),
  loading: () => null,
  render(loaded) {
    const Component = loaded.default;
    return <Component />;
  },
});
```

I've added the comment to tell webpack 3 that I want this chunk to be named app. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 24):

Ok, after 4 days I found the solution. I needed to add the chunkFilename line to my webpack config:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, './../public'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/',
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```

Then it works. I found it in the [webpack github page](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1949#issuecomment-308501388)

---

**EDIT:**

Addtional information for substitutions can be found in the webpack documentation for [output.chunkFilename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename) and for [output.filename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename)