# react-loadable gives a 404 error whenever I go to the route where the specific component is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been trying to code-split my concept website so far, but it just doesn't seem to work. I've got a STLMain component(STLMain.js):

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => (
  <div>
    STLMain
  </div>
);
```

Which is used in STLMainLoadable.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const loading = () => (
  <div>
    Loading...
  </div>
);

export default Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./STLMain'),
  loading
});
```

Which is then used in my Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './main_pages/Home';
import NotFound from './main_pages/NotFound';
import STLMainLoadable from './main_pages/STLMainLoadable';
import Navigation from './navigation/Navigation';

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/STLMain" component={STLMainLoadable} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And every time I go to localhost:8080/STLMain I get two errors in the console:

1.GET http://localhost:8080/0.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
 2.Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/0.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

And yes, I have syntax-dynamic-import babel plugin installed.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Seems that code splitting is working properly, you have probably an issue on _serving_ the resource. Try to load directly http://localhost:8080/0.bundle.js (or whatever name you have) in the browser.
I think you are not serving the JavaScript.

Are you using the yarn dev server or... ?

Comment: I'm using webpack dev-server

Comment: If I go to http://localhost:8080/0.bundle.js it says: "Cannot GET /0.bundle.js"

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, try setting `output.publicPath = '/'` in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
output: {
  ...
  publicPath: '/',
  ...
}
```

[Credit where credit is due](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645405/4941739)

Comment: Yes, it works, but instead of root publicPath: "/" you have to write down an url, your static files are served by your server.
In my case it was "/static/js"